# PHP/mail is sending emails to wrong mail server

Tags: php, sendmail, exim, mx-record, microsoft-office-365

Recently we have switched our email Exchange server from Intermedia to the Office 365. After that change web server (LAMP) is still sending emails to Intermedia. I have check `dig MX` for our domain and MX record comes as `ourdomain.com.mail.protection.outlook.com.` which is correct. At that point, as DNS has correct value for MX record, I have no idea what can be wrong.

PS.
Checked with a command line - same effect - email was sent to Intermedia insterad Office 365

`mail -s "Test Subject" user@ourdomain.com < /dev/null`

Comment: Is the mail actually routed based on the MX record? Or is sendmail configured to use a static mailroute 'MAIL_HUB' or 'SMART_HOST' settings come to mind as does the mailertable feature.

Comment: Good point. That server uses Exim4 and it looks like the local exim was authenticating to a remote host as a client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirm that your LAMP server is actually routing mail based on `MX` record and is not configured with a static mailroute to the old Exchange server.

For sendmail you would check for `MAIL_HUB` or `SMART_HOST` settings or the mailertable feature, for Exim [`route_list`](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_manualroute_router.html) settings.

Comment: I have updated smarthost and authentication (tested with regular email client - works) but a server from a smarthost permits authenticated senders through SASL and somehow is not working when PHP/mail is sending those emails (any email client works fine).  On SMTP server it comes as `postfix/smtpd[7260]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from rrcs-24-103-82-xyz.nyc.biz.rr.com[24.103.82.xyz]: 554 5.7.1 <root@ourdomain.com>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<root@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<staging-server>
`

Comment: I have added staging-server IP to a postfix config on a remote SMTP server as a part of  `mynetworks` but I'm not sure if it is right way to go in that case or just a shortcut.